# How to mix or append mp3 or wave files one after the other and save the resulting file onto the SD card in android?

Tags: android, soundpool

I have some mp3 files in my /res/raw folder. What I am doing is that, whenever a user clicks on a button a respective sound is played and after he is finished with pressing all the buttons, I want to club all those mp3 files together and a make a new audio file out of it and  save it to sd card.
I googled a lot and found `AudioTrack` and `SoundPool`classes useful but they couldn't resolve the issue.

Please Help.

Answer (score 1):

If that are plain mp3 streams in these files (no id3 tags), and their bitrate and other mp3 characteristics match, you can do as simple thing as to append all files into one resulting mp3 file.

This means opening InputStream of source files one after another, and write them to one FileOutputStream.

I tested this with 2 mp3 files and this works just fine.

Comment: Yep, it works fine. But this is not what I want. Appending the files will play the sounds one after the other. My application is a Piano kind of application. So you can guess, just appending won't help, because in that case I won't be able to record all the sounds that are playing simultaneously.

Comment: Then you need to make mixer. Decompress mp3, mix them in a wave buffer, save back as mp3 or other type.

Comment: But after hell lot of googling, I couldn't find a way to do that. And the worst thing is the application's requirement is android v2.2. So I kind even make use of OpenEL SL. Hopefully I could have got some help from it. Anyways, thanks.

Comment: Can you decode mp3 into raw PCM samples? Something like InputStream from mp3. If yes, then you're close to make own mixer where you'd blend multiple PCM streams into one PCM buffer.

Comment: Ohh... so how can I implement my own mixer then?

Comment: Decode PCM data as pairs of signed 16-bit values (one for left/right channel) into an array. To mix with other PCM data, simply add PCM values together for each sample. You need to watch for overflow of 16-bit values (use saturation). Then write sich mixed PCM data to a file (wav/mp3). 
Learn about PCM: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PCM